# Image labels in levelplot animation R

Tags: r, animation, raster, levelplot

Using the example from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698349/use-animate-with-series-of-levelplots-in-r-raster) , How can one possibly use`years` as title for each image?

**Example**:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(animation)
library(classInt)

r <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))
s <- stack(x=c(r, r*r, r*r*r, r*r*r*r))

classes <- classIntervals(values(r), n=5, style="fisher", precision = 3)
brks <- classes$brks
brks <- round(brks, 2)

saveGIF({
 for(i in c(1:nlayers(s))){
  l <- levelplot(s[[i]], colorkey=list(at=brks, labels=c(as.character(brks))), margin=FALSE,main=noquote(paste("",i)))
  plot(l)
 }
}, interval=0.2, movie.name="animation.gif")
```

The line `main=noquote(paste("",i))` will label each image in the animation as `1,2,3, etc..`. However, I would like to use `1919, 1920, 1921, etc..` instead. Is another `for loop` needed to generate `1919, 1920, 1921, etc..`?

The following do not work:

```
main=paste(1919,i)
main=paste(1919:1923,i)
```

**My actual rasterbrick has 100 layers**

Any suggestions for using the year as title for each image in the animation?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after a few thoughts:

```
main=paste(" ", 1918+i, sep='')
```

Assuming my data starts in `1919`, sequential years with a step of 1 will be added to each image.